# Select string by time

Tags: python, pandas, function, calculated-columns

I have a Dataframe and i'd like to classify the rows by some periods of time in a day.
I added a new column with the name: "turno" and this column was suposed to be classified in "NoiteAnterior", "Dia" and "Noite". I made a function to do this, but always comes the same classification, independent of the time. I need some help to know where i am been wrong. This is the function:

[time_test.xlsx](https://github.com/Ewallk/Fixacao/raw/main/time_test.xlsx)

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G24as.png)

```py
def turno(event):
  early_morning = dt.strptime('00:00:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()
  morning = dt.strptime('07:00:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()
  night = dt.strptime('19:00:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()

  for hour in event:
   if early_morning < hour < morning:
      return 'NoiteAnterior'
   elif morning < hour < night:
      return 'Dia'
   else:
      return 'Noite'
df['turno'] = turno(df['hora_inicio_evento'])
```

the column df['hora_inicio_evento']:
[['hora_inicio_turno']](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yetmW.png)

Comment: Can you tell us what the content of `df['hora_inicio_evento']` is. I assume python doesn't know what `hour` is and you always get `Noite` as a result.

Comment: it would be great to provide a sample of input/ouput as **text**

Comment: how could i fix it? It was suposed to be a for loop.

Comment: the link to the dataframe is available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
df = pd.DataFrame({'hora_inicio_evento':['00:10:00', '07:19:00', '19:00:01']})
def turno(event):
    early_morning = 0
    morning = 7
    night = 19
    hour = event.hour
    if early_morning <= hour and hour < morning:
      return 'NoiteAnterior'
    elif morning <= hour and hour < night:
      return 'Dia'
    else:
      return 'Noite'
df['turno'] = pd.to_datetime(df['hora_inicio_evento']).apply(turno)
```

Result:

[image]

Based on your comment:

```
df['turno'] = df['hora_inicio_evento'].apply(turno)
```

Result:

[image]

Based on the other comment:

```
df = pd.read_excel('time_test.xlsx')
df['turno'] = df['inicio_evento'].apply(turno)
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime

Comment: So the type of the column is datetime.time and no need to convert.

Comment: Edited the answer. If you provide sample df, such problems do not occur.

Comment: I'm sorry, i posted the dataframe itself for better understanding

Comment: The solution, works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I make the assumption that `df['hora_inicio_evento']` looks something like `'15:37:14'`. Then you should first extract the hour from this input. if it's already a datetime format, just use `event` everywhere instead of `event_time`.

```
def turno(event):
    early_morning = dt.strptime('00:00:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()
    morning = dt.strptime('07:00:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()
    night = dt.strptime('19:00:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()

    for e in event:
        event_time = dt.strptime(e, '%H:%M:%S').time()
        if early_morning.hour < event_time.hour <= morning.hour:
            return 'NoiteAnterior'
        elif morning.hour < event_time.hour <= night.hour:
            return 'Dia'
        else:
            return 'Noite'
```

Note that `for in` loops don't work like you wanted to use them, they iterate over every element of an iterable and take this single element into the loop denoted as, in your case `hour` and not the attribute `hour` of the iterable itself.

Comment: TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series

Comment: As I said, it depends what the content of `df['hora_inicio_evento']` is, if you don't tell us then how should we know how the code should look like.

Comment: the link to the dataframe is available.

Comment: Then you have to iterate over all events (almost as you had in already)

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. I posted the dataframe trying to help. Thanks in advance.